# ionic2 how to set click icons only and go other page

Tags: ionic2

**.html**

```
<ion-footer>
    <h1>登录方式：</h1>
      <ion-list>
        <button style="width:40%" ion-button round outline (click)= "QQLogin()">
          <ion-icon name="minan-qq"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <button style="width:40%" ion-button round outline (click)= "QQLogin()">
          <ion-icon name="minan-weixin"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <button style="width:40%" ion-button round outline (click)= "QQLogin()">
          <ion-icon name="minan-weibo"></ion-icon>
        </button>
        <button style="width:40%" ion-button round outline (click)= "QQLogin()">
          <ion-icon name="minan-facebook"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-list>
    </ion-footer>
```

[image]

Don't know how to clean the outline and button, just set a icons and when I click the icons then go to other functions or pages.

UPLOAD:  (when I use `icon-only`)

[image]

After remove style

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The case is that you're adding the `outline` attribute, this'll add only the border to the button. If you want only the icon you'll need the `clear` attribute.

```
<ion-footer>
  <h1>登录方式：</h1>
    <ion-list>
      <button style="width:40%" ion-button icon-only clear (click)= "QQLogin()">
        <ion-icon name="minan-qq"></ion-icon>
      </button>
      <button style="width:40%" ion-button icon-only clear (click)= "QQLogin()">
        <ion-icon name="minan-weixin"></ion-icon>
      </button>
      <button style="width:40%" ion-button icon-only clear (click)= "QQLogin()">
        <ion-icon name="minan-weibo"></ion-icon>
      </button>
      <button style="width:40%" ion-button icon-only clear (click)= "QQLogin()">
        <ion-icon name="minan-facebook"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-list>
  </ion-footer>
```

Also having inline styles is bad and there's a better way to distribute the buttons using the grid system

```
<ion-footer>
  <h1>登录方式：</h1>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-6>
        <button ion-button icon-only clear (click)= "QQLogin()">
          <ion-icon name="minan-qq"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-6>
        <button ion-button icon-only clear (click)= "QQLogin()">
          <ion-icon name="minan-weixin"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-6>
        <button ion-button icon-only clear (click)= "QQLogin()">
          <ion-icon name="minan-weibo"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-col>
      <ion-col col-6>
        <button ion-button icon-only clear (click)= "QQLogin()">
          <ion-icon name="minan-facebook"></ion-icon>
        </button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-footer>
```

This way it's cleaner and will have a better presentation, but it's up to you, it's just a sugestion.

Hope this helps

Comment: +1 because you did not only solve the issue of the OP, but also recommended how to avoid inline styles using Ionic's grid :)

Answer (score 0):

Im not quite sure if I understood you correctly, but in case you only want the icon the be rendered the icon-only attribute is what you are looking for. So try this:

```html
<button ion-button icon-only (click)= "QQLogin()">
          <ion-icon name="minan-facebook"></ion-icon>
</button>

<!-- use this for round icon -->
<button ion-button icon-only round (click)= "QQLogin()">
          <ion-icon name="minan-facebook"></ion-icon>
</button>
```

You can look up the documentation for further details here:
https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/button/Button/

Comment: I mean only icons there, no round lines, and I can click the icons

Comment: I edited the answer now, pls use the exact same code as in the example and tell me if it works. You can keep the round attribute though.

Comment: I tried this one ald.. not working for me.. I just want the Icons..and I uploaded when I used that code showing..

Comment: Did you use <button ion-button icon-only (click)= "QQLogin()"> without any changes or did you still keep the "style=40%" attribute? The style attribute does change the output for me as well. In case you have, pls post exactly what code you tried with the picture.

Comment: Still cannot.. I upload new image in question

Comment: This should be your icon I think. Try adjusting the facebook icon like this:         <button ion-button round (click)= "QQLogin()">
          <ion-icon name="minan-facebook"></ion-icon></button>